# Maintaining proportionate div heights

Tags: css

I have a graph that adds bars or removes bars according to the size of the screen. For example, if the size is bigger than 800px, another bar is added to the graph. Or if it is less than 800px, the last a bar is removed.

I use an equation `height:cal(100%*number/max);` to find the height of the bars in the graph. But I also have media queries that remove or add bars. I would like the highest bar to always be 100% of the height and the others to be proportionate.

Is there a CSS solution to keep proportionate div heights?

1. Resize browser more than 800px.
2. See how the last dt is 100% of the height of the graph.
3. Resize browser to less than 800px
4. See how the last dt is only 50% of the height for first graph but I want to maintain proportions like graph two.

I have:

```css
.bargraph{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.bargraph dt{
  margin:0 10px;
  border:6px solid blue;
  background:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  flex-grow:1;
}
 .bargraph dt:nth-of-type(3){
  display:none;
 }
@media only screen and (min-width:800px){
 .bargraph dt:nth-of-type(3){
  display:block;
 }
 #want{
  display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<dl class="bargraph">
  <dt style="height:20%;"></dt>
  <dt style="height:40%;"></dt>
  <dt style="height:100%"></dt>
</dl>

<div id="want">
  I want:
  <dl class="bargraph" id="want">
    <dt style="height:50%;"></dt>
    <dt style="height:100%;"></dt>
  </dl>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a9mm7ttn/

Comment: Not sure your requirements are possible with pure CSS. But here's a shot: https://jsfiddle.net/a9mm7ttn/1/